# What transformations are permitted before a t-test for significance?

Tags: logistic, statistical-significance, t-test, data-transformation, growth-model

I have been using t-tests to test for significant differences between the means of populations. Specifically, I am trying to determine if revenues have increased significantly before and after a marketing campaign was activated. I have created a custom method to prepare data for the t-test, and I was hoping you could tell me if this process is mathematically legal or not. I will append your email to my finished product so my boss knows what I’m doing is ok.

First, I am given a table of week numbers with corresponding dollar amount of revenue for that week. I am also given the date of when the marketing campaign started. The data looks something like this: [image]
(where the black line is the trendline for a discrete number of points and the red line is when the campaign is active)

I take the log of revenue so my slopes are each constant:

[image]
Then I take the log again so my two groups each have a slope of zero but a different mean value:

[image]
I think this transformation for the data is good because a t-test for significance looks at significant difference of means, not slope between populations. Now, the mean value for each population is the exponential growth rate, which is what I want to be testing for a significant difference. I can now report the mean value for each population as the growth rate for each period.

Are these transformations statistically legal? A sentence or two would be sufficient.

Comment: The elephant in the room you're not talking about is the assumption of independence of successive observations.

Comment: I do think independence is a fair assumption because many of these customers are not repeat buyers. I am trying to remove the influence of the underlying growth with the log log transformations.

Comment: The seller is maintaining continuity; that imparts dependence. The major point here is that measuring a dfference is easy, but a P-value depends intimately on a data generating process.

Comment: Why are you considering data transformation? If data are not normal and the purpose of transformation is to get data that are more nearly normal, then you might use a nonparametric test to compare locations. If variances are not equal and the purpose of transformation is to 'stabilize' the variances, then maybe use a procedure like a Welch 2-sample t test or `oneway.test` in R that do not require equal variances.

Comment: I am performing this transformation for two reasons. One, to report the growth rates of each population. Two, to normalize the data. What is the the advantage of using Welch's over a t-test on transformed data?

Comment: Also, it is necessary to transform the data or else the underlying growth will make it seem like the two populations are different without any change in growth. Since the test population happens after the control, a steady rate of growth would increase the mean of the test population without any change to the growth rate.